# Iterative equivalent a recursive algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to modify this program to their equivalent iterative but it becomes very difficult to me because as yet i'm still a newbie, it comes to an algorithm that decomposes a number into its prime factors, here the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <cmath>

std::map< int, std::pair<int, int> > decompositions;

void descompon_number(int num, int root, int i = 2 )
{
    auto iterator = decompositions.find(num);
    if (iterator == decompositions.end())
    {
        if (num > 1 && i <= root)
        {
            if (num % i == 0)
            {
                int n = num / i;
                decompositions[num] = std::make_pair(i, n);
                descompon_number(n, (int) std::sqrt(n));
            }
            else
                descompon_number(num, root, i + 1);
        }
        else
            decompositions[num] = std::make_pair(num, 1);
    }
}

void show(int num, int factor, int exponent, int see)
{
    auto pair = decompositions[num];
    if (num <= 1 || factor != pair.first)
    {
        if (see)
            std::cout << factor;
        if (exponent > 1 && see)
            std::cout << "^" << exponent;
        if (pair.first > 1 && see)
            std::cout << " * ";
        exponent = 0;
    }
    if (num > 1)
        show(pair.second, pair.first, exponent + 1, see);
}

void descompon(int a, int b, int see)
{
    if (a <= b)
    {
        descompon_number(a, (int) std::sqrt(a));
        if (see)
            std::cout << a << " = ";
        show(a, decompositions[a].first, 0, see);
        if (see)
            std::cout << std::endl;
        descompon(a + 1, b, see);
    }
}

int main()
{
    descompon(2, 100, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Someone can help me out with this

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27660881/862351) might help. (Disclaimer : I wrote the linked answer.)

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding how your algorithm works, but I know one thing: this can be done much easier, in like 5-10 lines of code.

Comment: in that case I doubt it fast

Comment: I see 3 different recursive functions.  Are you unable to make any of them iterative?

Comment: What is your question...? And why does your code have literally _no_ documenting comments explaining what it does?

Answer (score 3):

Finding prime factors iteratively is not very complicated.

Here's the pseudocode how to do this.

Let `P` be a list of the first `n` prime numbers, such that `Pn <= sqrt(m)`.

```
array findPrimeFactors(m)
    answer = new array
    for p in P
        while m can be divided by p
            m = m / p
            answer.append(p)
        if m == 1
            break
    return answer
```

Note: empty array is returned if m is prime.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an erastotenes' sieve to compute prime numbers, and later you can use the algorithm posted by *popovitsj*.

The following code can be optimized, but its main purpose is to show you how to proceed.

Complete example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// Returns a vector containing the first <number> prime numbers
vector<int> erastotenes_sieve(int number)
{
    vector<int> result;
    int *sieve = new int[number]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) sieve[i] = 0;


    // Traverse the sieve marking multiples.
    for (int i = 2; i < number / 2; i++)
        for (int j = i + i; j < number; j += i)
            sieve[j] = 1;

    // Collect unaffected indexes, those are prime numbers.
    for (int i = 2; i < number; i++)
        if (!sieve[i])
            result.push_back(i);

    delete [] sieve;

    return result;
}

vector<int> descompon_number(int number)
{
    vector<int> result;

    if (number == 1 || number == 0)
    {
        result.push_back(number);
        return result;
    }

    for (int &prime : erastotenes_sieve(number))
    {
        while (number % prime == 0 && number != 1)
        {
            number /= prime;
            result.push_back(prime);
        }
    }

    return result;
}


int main()
{
    for (auto &i : descompon_number(20))
    {
        cout << i << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```